# Formatting appendices in TOC, report class, with other detailed formatting for chapters, etc

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, report, appendix

I am creating a template for use in Report document class with pdfLaTeX compiler in Overleaf. My last hiccup is getting the TOC for the appendices to look a specific way. I have a lot of specific formatting, especially in the `% format headers` and `% format table of contents` in my example below that I think is controlling the look, but I am still new to LaTeX and not sure how to untangle it.

Here is how it currently looks:

[image]

I want to change the following:

1. Remove the subsections. I tried `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}`, as commented-out in my [MRE]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but removed the figures on my list of figures page.
2. Change the yellow highlight to say, "Appendix A The Name of My First Appendix ..... #" (and "Appendix B Foo ..... #"), in all caps. The indentation should be the same as "References." Also, the appendices have to go after the references.

Here is the code, which makes a 10 page PDF.

```
%-------------------------------------------------------
% Dummy Chapter 1
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{ChapterA.tex}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section Name}
Here is some text, see Figure \ref{fig:a}.
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width = 0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{An example figure.} 
  \label{fig:a}
\end{figure}
\subsection{Subsection Name}
Here is a subsection, see \cite{einstein1906new}.
\end{filecontents*}

%-------------------------------------------------------
% Dummy Abstract
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{Abstract.tex}
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\begin{center}
  \fontsize{18pt}{0pt}\selectfont\MakeUppercase{\textbf{abstract}}
\end{center}

\vspace*{24pt}

This is the abstract.
\end{filecontents*}

%-------------------------------------------------------
% Dummy Appendix A
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{AppendixA.tex}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{60pt}
{\fontsize{18pt}{0pt} \MakeUppercase{\textbf{Appendix A}}} \\
\vspace*{24pt}
{\fontsize{18pt}{0pt} \MakeUppercase{\textbf{The name of my first appendix}}}
\vspace*{100pt}
\end{center}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\appendix
\chapter{The name of my first appendix}
\lipsum[1]
\section{A section in my appendix}
Here is some text, see Figure \ref{fig:b}.
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width = 0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{An example figure.} 
  \label{fig:b}
\end{figure}
\subsection{A subsection in my appendix}
Here is a subsection.
\end{filecontents*}

%-------------------------------------------------------
% Dummy References
\begin{filecontents*}{refs.bib}
@article{einstein1906new,
  title={A new determination of molecular dimensions},
  author={Einstein, Albert},
  journal={Ann. Phys.},
  volume={19},
  pages={289--306},
  year={1906}
}
\end{filecontents*}

%-------------------------------------------------------
% Preamble
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% set page & paragraph dimensions
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}

% set font
\usepackage[sfdefault]{carlito}

% set-up frontmatter, mainmatter, backmatter
\makeatletter
\newcommand\frontmatter{
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{roman}}
\newcommand\mainmatter{
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}}
\newcommand\backmatter{
    \if@openright
        \cleardoublepage
    \else
        \clearpage
    \fi
}
\makeatother

% format headers
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand{\chapterjustification}{}
\newcommand{\chapterfont}{\normalfont}
\newcommand{\chapterfontsize}{\fontsize{22pt}{0pt}\selectfont}

\titleformat{\chapter}%
    {\chapterjustification\chapterfont\chapterfontsize\bfseries\MakeUppercase}%
    {\thechapter}{0.5in}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{80pt}{40pt}

\titleformat{\section}%
    {\normalfont\fontsize{14pt}{0pt}\selectfont\bfseries\MakeUppercase}%
    {\thesection}{0.5in}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{24pt}{12pt}

\titleformat{\subsection}%
    {\normalfont\fontsize{14pt}{0pt}\selectfont\bfseries}%
    {\thesubsection}{0.5in}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{18pt}{12pt}

% format references fonts, etc.
\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}{%
  \titleformat{\chapter}%
    {\normalfont\fontsize{14pt}{0pt}\bfseries\filcenter}%
    {\thechapter}{0.5in}{\MakeUppercase}%
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{12pt}
}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\AddToHook{cmd/bibsection/after}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}%
}

\def\bibfont{\fontsize{11pt}{0pt}\selectfont\hyphenpenalty=10000}

% format table of contents
\usepackage{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{0.2in}

\titlecontents{chapter}[0.5in]{%
    \addvspace{12pt}\bfseries}{%
    \contentslabel{0.5in}\MakeUppercase}{%
    \hspace*{-0.5in}\MakeUppercase}{%
    \titlerule*[0.5pc]{.}\contentspage} % dot density

\titlecontents{section}[1in]{\bfseries}{%
    \contentslabel{0.5in}\MakeUppercase}{%
    \hspace*{-1in}\MakeUppercase}{%
    \titlerule*[0.5pc]{.}\contentspage}
    
\titlecontents{subsection}[1.5in]{\selectfont}{%
    \contentslabel{0.5in}}{%
    \hspace*{-1in}}{%
    \titlerule*[0.5pc]{.}\contentspage}

\newcommand{\insertTOC}{\begingroup
    \cleardoublepage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
    \renewcommand{\chapterjustification}{\centering}
    \renewcommand{\chapterfontsize}{\fontsize{16pt}{0pt}\selectfont}
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{24pt}
    \tableofcontents
    \endgroup}

% format list of figures & list of tables pages
\newcommand{\insertLOF}{\begingroup
    \cleardoublepage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
    \renewcommand{\chapterjustification}{\centering}
    \renewcommand{\chapterfontsize}{\fontsize{16pt}{0pt}\selectfont}
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{24pt}
    {\let\oldnumberline\numberline %
        \renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline} %
        \listoffigures}
    \endgroup}

\newcommand{\insertLOT}{\begingroup
    \cleardoublepage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
    \renewcommand{\chapterjustification}{\centering}
    \renewcommand{\chapterfontsize}{\fontsize{16pt}{0pt}\selectfont}
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{24pt}
    {\let\oldnumberline\numberline %
        \renewcommand{\numberline}{\tablename~\oldnumberline} %
        \listoftables}
    \endgroup}

% load hyperref last to minimize conflicts
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue}

%-------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\include{Abstract}
\insertTOC
\insertLOF
\insertLOT

\mainmatter
\include{ChapterA}

\backmatter
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{refs}

\begin{appendices}
% \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
% this removes the list of figures
\include{AppendixA}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
%-------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You should add `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}` between `\tableofcontents` and `\listoffigures`.  Figures and tables are implemented at tocdepth=1.  Counters are always set globally.

Comment: Thank you! This, combined with @Werner answer, worked. I used `\frontmatter` // `\include{Abstract}` // `\insertTOC` // `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}`// `\insertLOF`// `\insertLOT` // in @Werner answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The placement of the change of `tocdepth` shouldn't just be placed anywhere; it should be placed at the appropriate location within the ToC from which point onward you want the change to apply. In your case, around the time you call

\chapter{The name of my first appendix}

so that `\section`s after this `\chapter` doesn't appear in the ToC. In short, within `AppendixA.tex`.

In terms of the `APPENDIX` prefix for appendix chapters, one can do the same. I've added a `\chapterprefix` to your setup (blank at first), which is updated within `AppendixA.tex`.

[image]

```
%-------------------------------------------------------
% Dummy Chapter 1
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{ChapterA.tex}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section Name}
Here is some text, see Figure \ref{fig:a}.
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width = 0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{An example figure.} 
  \label{fig:a}
\end{figure}
\subsection{Subsection Name}
Here is a subsection.
\end{filecontents*}

%-------------------------------------------------------
% Dummy Abstract
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{Abstract.tex}
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\begin{center}
  \fontsize{18pt}{0pt}\selectfont\MakeUppercase{\textbf{abstract}}
\end{center}

\vspace*{24pt}

This is the abstract.
\end{filecontents*}

%-------------------------------------------------------
% Dummy Appendix A
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{AppendixA.tex}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{60pt}
{\fontsize{18pt}{0pt} \MakeUppercase{\textbf{Appendix A}}} \\
\vspace*{24pt}
{\fontsize{18pt}{0pt} \MakeUppercase{\textbf{The name of my first appendix}}}
\vspace*{100pt}
\end{center}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\appendix
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}% Only show up to \chapter in ToC from this point forward
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\renewcommand{\protect\chapterprefix}{\protect\hspace*{-0.5in}APPENDIX\protect\hspace*{0.6in}}}%
\chapter{The name of my first appendix}
\lipsum[1]
\section{A section in my appendix}
Here is some text, see Figure \ref{fig:b}.
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width = 0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{An example figure.} 
  \label{fig:b}
\end{figure}
\subsection{A subsection in my appendix}
Here is a subsection.
\end{filecontents*}

%-------------------------------------------------------
% Preamble
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% set page & paragraph dimensions
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5in}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}

% set font
\usepackage[sfdefault]{carlito}

% set-up frontmatter, mainmatter, backmatter
\makeatletter
\newcommand\frontmatter{
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{roman}}
\newcommand\mainmatter{
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}}
\newcommand\backmatter{
    \if@openright
        \cleardoublepage
    \else
        \clearpage
    \fi
}
\makeatother

% format headers
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand{\chapterjustification}{}
\newcommand{\chapterfont}{\normalfont}
\newcommand{\chapterfontsize}{\fontsize{22pt}{0pt}\selectfont}

\titleformat{\chapter}%
    {\chapterjustification\chapterfont\chapterfontsize\bfseries\MakeUppercase}%
    {\thechapter}{0.5in}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{80pt}{40pt}

\titleformat{\section}%
    {\normalfont\fontsize{14pt}{0pt}\selectfont\bfseries\MakeUppercase}%
    {\thesection}{0.5in}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{24pt}{12pt}

\titleformat{\subsection}%
    {\normalfont\fontsize{14pt}{0pt}\selectfont\bfseries}%
    {\thesubsection}{0.5in}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{18pt}{12pt}

% format table of contents
\usepackage{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{0.2in}
\newcommand{\chapterprefix}{}
\titlecontents{chapter}[0.5in]{%
    \addvspace{12pt}\bfseries}{%
    \chapterprefix\contentslabel{0.5in}\MakeUppercase}{%
    \hspace*{-0.5in}\MakeUppercase}{%
    \titlerule*[0.5pc]{.}\contentspage} % dot density

\titlecontents{section}[1in]{\bfseries}{%
    \contentslabel{0.5in}\MakeUppercase}{%
    \hspace*{-1in}\MakeUppercase}{%
    \titlerule*[0.5pc]{.}\contentspage}
    
\titlecontents{subsection}[1.5in]{\selectfont}{%
    \contentslabel{0.5in}}{%
    \hspace*{-1in}}{%
    \titlerule*[0.5pc]{.}\contentspage}

\newcommand{\insertTOC}{\begingroup
    \cleardoublepage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
    \renewcommand{\chapterjustification}{\centering}
    \renewcommand{\chapterfontsize}{\fontsize{16pt}{0pt}\selectfont}
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{24pt}
    \tableofcontents
    \endgroup}

% format list of figures & list of tables pages
\newcommand{\insertLOF}{\begingroup
    \cleardoublepage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
    \renewcommand{\chapterjustification}{\centering}
    \renewcommand{\chapterfontsize}{\fontsize{16pt}{0pt}\selectfont}
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{24pt}
    {\let\oldnumberline\numberline %
        \renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline} %
        \listoffigures}
    \endgroup}

\newcommand{\insertLOT}{\begingroup
    \cleardoublepage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
    \renewcommand{\chapterjustification}{\centering}
    \renewcommand{\chapterfontsize}{\fontsize{16pt}{0pt}\selectfont}
    \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{24pt}
    {\let\oldnumberline\numberline %
        \renewcommand{\numberline}{\tablename~\oldnumberline} %
        \listoftables}
    \endgroup}

% load hyperref last to minimize conflicts
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue}

%-------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\include{Abstract}
\insertTOC
\insertLOF
\insertLOT

\mainmatter
\include{ChapterA}

\backmatter

\begin{appendices}
% \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
% this removes the list of figures
\include{AppendixA}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help and another great answer! This version still omits the Figure #s on the List of Figures page for me (but the TOC is perfect). However, with @John Kormylo comment, I made the small change of  `\frontmatter` // `\include{Abstract}` // `\insertTOC` // `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}`// `\insertLOF`// `\insertLOT` // in your answer, and it is perfect now.